# Visual representation of the Pythagoras tree in Java

Tags: java, graphics2d, fractals

I want to make a visual representation of the Pythagoras tree using Java, the code outputs a PNG fixed image.

I started by defining Vector class which starting from two vector components (x,y) can rotate the vector, scale it or add it to another vector.

```
public class Vector {
    public double x;
    public double y;

    public Vector(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Vector rotated(double alpha) {
        double x1 = Math.cos(alpha) * x - Math.sin(alpha) * y;
        double y1 = Math.sin(alpha) * x + Math.cos(alpha) * y;
        Vector vRotated = new Vector(x1, y1);
        return vRotated;
    }

    public Vector scaled(double s) {
        double x1 = x * s;
        double y1 = y * s;
        Vector vScaled = new Vector(x1, y1);
        return vScaled;
    }

   public Vector added(Vector v) {
       double x1 = this.x+v.x;
       double y1 = this.y+v.y;
       Vector vAdded = new Vector(x1,y1);
       return vAdded;
   }
}
```

I have also writen the method for creating the initial image and background and saving it to the desired path

```
  public static void createPythagorasTreeImage(int startSize) throws IOException {
    // Creation of the image object
    int height = 5 * startSize;
    int width = 8 * startSize;
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    // Create a Graphics2D object from the image and set a white background
    Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
    g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    // Initial position and orientation of the first segment
    Vector startPos = new Vector(width / 2, startSize);
    Vector up = new Vector(0, 1);

    // Start the recursion.
    drawSegment(g, startPos, up, startSize, height);

    // Save the image as PNG
    String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase(); // different for win and unix
    String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + (OS.indexOf("win") >= 0 ? "\\" : "/") + "pythagorasTree.png";
    System.out.println("Writing pythagoras-tree image to: " + filePath);
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(filePath));
    }
```

I have read on wikipedia on how to the tree works, and want to now implement the algorithm.
What I need help with is implementing these two methods using Graphics2D (which I'm not very familiar with):

```
public static void drawRotatedRect(Graphics2D g, Vector pos, Vector up, int a, int height) {
    }
```

This method should Draw a square using Graphics2D (maybe using g.fillPolygon()?), at position pos, up the vector that indicates the rotation of the square by indicating which direction is up for the square, a is the side of the square and height is the height of the drawing space.

```
 public static void drawSegment(Graphics2D g, Vector pos, Vector up, int a, int height) {
    }
```

This method should draw the first square using the previous method, than compute the positions and rotations of the two new squares and draw them, repeat this recursively until a square has a very small side length (2px).

This is my understanding for the Pythagoras tree, I managed to write the majority of the code and it seems that the idea is correct, only if I get the two missing methods to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the `Graphics2D` context by drawing a Path2D with floating point (or double) precision. I reccoment this, since you will notice that using int precision might give you weird effects.

To draw a path, do:

```java
Path2D.Double rectangle = new Path2D.Double();

rectangle.moveTo(0, 0);
// ... basically draw the four points of the rectangle here. 
rectangle.closePath();

g.setColor(yourColorOfChoice);
g.fill(rectangle);
```

Notice that you need to draw the rectangular shapes manually, since they need ot be rotated, and `Graphics2D` does not do well with rotations. You could try using inherent rotations, but you will pixelate your context, and you won't like it.

I am very much looking forward to your results. Could you paste the final image into your question, once you are done :)?